# Brezis Analysis Problem about solutions of $-\Delta u=V(x) e^{u}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, maximum-principle, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I'm looking for someone who has read the article written by Brezis & Merle (https://doi.org/10.1080/03605309108820797). Because I'm confused when I saw *the maximum principle*. For example, See formula (3) in the proof of **Theorem 1**.

Brezis claimed that we only need $u\in L^{1}(\Omega), V(x)e^{u}\in L^{1}(\Omega)$ to ensure $-\Delta u=V(x)e^{u}$ make sense in the sense of distribution. When reading this article, I found he never uses the property of Sobolev space. So at first I believe in this paper, a solution $u(x)$ does not need to be in a Sobolev space.

But when I finish reading and review, everything fits the assumption except *the maximum principle*. I only learned that maximum principle when $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$, and  its proof can't extend to this article.

> **Question**： Is that means Brezis achieved another maximum principle without existence of weak derivative? Or he indicated that we must consider solutions in $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$?

Maybe we can compare it to the equation$-\Delta u=\lambda \delta_{0}$ with or without boundary condition.

Comment: Solved. See No. 187 publication on  Prof. Brezis's website. In short, his setting of test function for weak solution is $C_0^2(\bar{\Omega})$.